# Upper bounds on the sectional curvature of the real Grassmannian

Tags: riemannian-geometry, symmetric-spaces

Consider the real Grassmannian as the symmetric space $\operatorname{Gr}(n,k) \cong \operatorname{O}(n)/(\operatorname{O}(k) \times \operatorname{O}(n-k))$ for $n \geq 3$, $k \geq 2$, where the metric is that induced from the bi-invariant metric on $\operatorname{O}(n)$, $\langle X,Y\rangle =\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}(X^\intercal Y)$. The sectional curvature on $\operatorname{O}(n)$ with this bi-invariant metric is given by

$$
\operatorname{sec}_{\operatorname{O}(n)}(X, Y) = \frac{1}{4}\lVert[X,Y]\rVert^2.
$$
where the norm is that induced by the scalar product.

Writing $\mathfrak{h} = \mathfrak{o}(n-k) \oplus \mathfrak{o}(k)$ and $\mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{h}^\perp \subset \mathfrak{o}(n)$, by the O'Neill's formula and identifying a tangent space of the Grassmannian with a subspace of the Lie algebra of $\operatorname{O}(n)$, we have that the sectional curvature of $\operatorname{Gr}(n,k)$ for a pair of orthonormal vectors $X, Y \in \mathfrak{m}$

$$
\operatorname{sec}_{\operatorname{Gr}(n,k)}(X, Y) = \frac{1}{4}\lVert[X,Y]\rVert^2 + \frac{3}{4}\lVert [X,Y]_{\mathfrak{h}}\rVert^2 = \lVert[X,Y]\rVert^2
$$
since $[\mathfrak{m}, \mathfrak{m}] \subset \mathfrak{h}$.
Using now the bounds for the Lie bracket in $\operatorname{O}(n)$ (see [this other MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/343406/145929))
$$
\operatorname{sec}_{\operatorname{Gr}(n,k)}(X, Y) \leq 4.
$$

This bound is not tight, as it can be seen by looking at the equality cases for the inequality used, as per Lemma 2.5 in [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S000187081300385X).

On the other hand, in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC539132/pdf/pnas00119-0088.pdf) the author announces (without proof) in Theorem 3a that
$$
\operatorname{sec}_{\operatorname{Gr}(n,k)}(X, Y) \leq 2.
$$
and even gives examples in Theorem 5a of a submanifold where this bound is achieved.

Is there any reference in which the tighter bound of $2$ is computed? Is there a reference where the tightness of the bound $2$ is also derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof can be found in [this article by Hildebrandt, Jost, and Widman](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01389161.pdf). I reproduce here the proof for completeness.

Consider the usual representation of $\mathfrak{m}$ as matrices of the form

$$
\mathfrak{m} = \left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & A \\
    -A^\intercal & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\bigm\vert A \in \mathbb{R}^{(n-k)\times k} \right\}
$$

We can write the sectional curvature of the Grassmannian at $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{(n-k)\times k}$ for two matrices such that $\operatorname{tr}(A^\intercal B)$ in terms of their Frobenius norm as

$$
\operatorname{sec}_{\operatorname{Gr}(n,k)}(X, Y) = 
\frac{
\lVert AB^\intercal - BA^\intercal \rVert_F^2 + 
\lVert A^\intercal B - B^\intercal A \rVert_F^2
}{
2\lVert A \rVert_F^2 \lVert B \rVert_F^2
}
$$

In the rest, we will be deliberately imprecise with the limits of the indices to not clutter innecessarily the proof.

Considering the SVD of A, we may assume that $A$ just has non-zero elements in its main diagonal. We can then write the numerator of the sectional curvature as

$$
N = \sum_{i\neq j} (a_{ii}b_{ji}-a_{jj}b_{ij})^2 + 
\sum_{i\neq j} (a_{ii}b_{ij}-a_{jj}b_{ji})^2
$$
$$
D = 2(\sum_i a_{ii}^2)(\sum_{j,k}b_{jk}^2)
$$

We can bound $N$ using $(a+b)^2 \leq 2(a^2 + b^2)$ on the summation terms so that

$$
N \leq
4\sum_{i\neq j} a_{ii}^2b_{ji}^2 + 4\sum_{i\neq j} a_{ii}^2b_{ij}^2 \leq 
4\sum_{i} a_{ii}^2(\sum_{j \neq i}b_{ji}^2 + \sum_{j \neq i}b_{ij}^2)
$$

and we can bound the denominator as

$$
D = 2(\sum_i a_{ii}^2)(\sum_j b^2_{ji} + \sum_k\sum_{j \neq i}b_{kj}^2)
\geq \frac{1}{2}N.
$$

In the paper they also show the tightness of this bound considering $A = \mathrm{Id}$ and $B =\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.